# Periodically trigger a workflow

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, timer-service

Here's the situation. I have a list/content type with a column called "frequency". Based on the item's frequency value, a workflow should be triggered automatically every day / month / year. This basically creates a task.

How can this be achieved best? The workflow itself would be designed using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to just let the workflow itself do the work.

Just let the workflow start when a new item is created.
Then depending on whether it should run initially the do the following:

If it should run initially:

1. Do the real work of the workflow
2. Check frequency and delay for that period
3. Loop back to beginning

If it shouldn't run initially:

1. Check frequency and delay for that period
2. Do the real work of the workflow
3. Loop back to beginning

Comment: Thanks Per! I am a bit stuck on the "delay for that period" part cause the workflow needs to be triggered again every X days. However, when I delay I need to be able to trigger it without the previous workflow being completed. It seems now the workflow only triggers when the "real work" has completed. The "real work" is not a precondition to start up a new workflow... do you have any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer job that will check the frequency of the listitem and start the workflow programmatically on the item.